# Can't access internet on a Virtual Box

Tags: networking, wireless, virtualbox

I am having difficulty setting up the internet on a Virtual Box.

Here are the network settings

[image: img_network_settings]

I set the adapter to bridged and the MAC address to be the same as that of the WiFi interface on my host machine, which I believe should forward the packets received on `en0` to the virtual interface as well. Am I doing something wrong?

Ubuntu verion: 18.04.1

Comment: Your VirtualBox settings appear to be correct, but it’ll be important to know what version of Ubuntu you’ve put on the VM and whether that installation can see the network. What does `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A2` return?

Comment: Edited the description, and it returns `00:03.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller [8086:100e] (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter [8086:001e]
 Kernel driver in use: e1000`

Answer (score 2):

I beleive you should use different mac than your host. In bridged mode, your vm acts like a phsical computer on your network and there should NOT be two computer with same mac address.

Comment: after a bit of reading, bridging isn't a part of wlan spec so how come bridging would work for a wlan interface? also, I tried using NAT which seemed to do the trick